# Bypass gRPC interceptor for specific endpoint

Tags: java, grpc, interceptor, grpc-java, health-check

Lately I have been struggling with one problem : I can't ignore `io.grpc.ServerInterceptor` for some endpoints, in my case the health-check one, provided under the hood by `io.grpc.protobuf.services.HealthServiceImpl`

The only option that I could find is to define a new ServerInterceptor that retrieves the endpoint name through an `io.grpc.Listener#onMessage` and close the gRPC call before doing any of my other ServerInteceptor if the endpoint matches.

However, this solution does not seem very elegant.
Is there a way, maybe from configuration, to ignore my existing interceptors ?

This issue is new, when I started using gRPC version **1.42.2**. Everything was working well under gRPC **1.35.0**.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT :** some code

In my configuration class :

```java
@Bean
HealthStatusManager healthStatusManager() {
        return new HealthStatusManager();
}

@Bean
Server server(
        Service1 service1,
        Service2 service2,
        HealthStatusManager healthStatusManager
) {
    return ServerBuilder.forPort(9090)
            .addService(service1)
            .addService(service2)
            .addService(healthStatusManager.getHealthService())
            // I do not want these to interceptors to be executed for healthService
            .intercept(new Interceptor1()) 
            .intercept(new Interceptor2())
            .build();
}
```

The Interceptor2 does some checks that I don't need for my health-check service (and even, that prevents it from working properly)

Comment: would be great if you can give us a minimum reproducible project? at least a little bit of code so that I can help

Comment: Yes, added some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protobuf/gRPC reflection could be useful in this case. I would implement such a solution by doing the following:

Let's say that I have the following service:

```proto
service HealthService {
    //...
}
```

that would generate a `HealthServiceGrpc` class and in this class there is a `public static final String SERVICE_NAME` (**note that if you are using java lite version of gRPC this is maybe not existing**).

After that the `ServerCall` class that you have in your `ServerInterceptor.interceptCall` has a `getMethodDescriptor()` function. This returns a descriptor for the endpoint that you are calling. From that you can get the service name. With all that, a basic implementation would be:

```java
public class Interceptor1 implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        if (Objects.equals(call.getMethodDescriptor().getServiceName(), HealthServiceGrpc.SERVICE_NAME))
            return next.startCall(call, headers);

        return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(next.startCall(call, headers)) {
            //...
        };
    }
}
```

To explain a little bit here, if the name of the service is HealthService, we just go ahead and make the call, otherwise we go through the interceptor implementation.

Obviously, after that, if you want something less manual you might want to use a Singleton instance which register which interceptor to skip for which service.

Comment: Your solution looks a bit like what I figured out, but yours is far cleaner. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

we had the same issue and did something different that I find simpler.

In your Server Builder you can attach interceptors to specific endpoints like so:

```
@Bean
HealthStatusManager healthStatusManager() {
        return new HealthStatusManager();
}

@Bean
Server server(
        Service1 service1,
        Service2 service2,
        HealthStatusManager healthStatusManager
) {
    return ServerBuilder.forPort(9090)
            .addService(ServerInterceptor.intercept(service1, new Interceptor1(), new Interceptor2()))
            .addService(ServerInterceptor.intercept(service2, new Interceptor1(), new Interceptor2()))
            .addService(healthStatusManager.getHealthService())
            .build();
}
```

Hope this does the trick for you!